# unfortunately the application stopped: AdMob Error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, admob

```
The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log) : AdMob
```

I have followed the steps(copy and pasted it as it is) given in the documentation at developers admob site.
and have implemented their example in eclipse ADT. It still not working..and the application stops unexpectedly.

here is the
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

-----MainActivity.java-----

```
package com.google.android.gms.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

--Manifest File--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

--Error Log--

```
eclipse.buildId=v22.0.5-757759
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error
Sun Jun 14 17:13:05 IST 2015
No command output when running: 'am start -n    com.google.android.gms.example/com.google.android.gms.example.MainActivity -a  android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device  emulator-5554

com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:435)
at    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(    ActivityLaunchAction.java:67)
at    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(    ActivityLaunchAction.java:109)
at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doLaunchActi    on(AndroidLaunchController.java:1286)
at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doLaunchActi    on(AndroidLaunchController.java:1298)
at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launchApp(An    droidLaunchController.java:1270)
at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.simpleLaunch    (AndroidLaunchController.java:906)
at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.continueLaun    ch(AndroidLaunchController.java:748)
at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launch(AndroidLaunchController.java:570)
at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.doLaunch(Launch    ConfigDelegate.java:322)
at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchCo    nfigDelegate.java:238)
at       org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.j      ava:855)
at     org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.j    ava:704)
at     org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:10    47)
at   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

--logcat--

```
06-14 08:06:11.481: E/dalvikvm(1168): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.example.MainActivity.onCreate
06-14 08:06:11.481: W/dalvikvm(1168): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 639 (Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/example/MainActivity;
06-14 08:06:11.491: D/dalvikvm(1168): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000f
06-14 08:06:11.531: D/dalvikvm(1168): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x120d at 0x13 in Lcom/google/android/gms/example/MainActivity;.onCreate
06-14 08:06:12.562: D/AndroidRuntime(1168): Shutting down VM
06-14 08:06:12.562: W/dalvikvm(1168): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms.example/com.google.android.gms.example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.google.android.gms.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     ... 11 more
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms.example-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms.example-1, /system/lib]]
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
06-14 08:06:12.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: Could you provide your full error log / exception?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post with error log. @Mdlc

Comment: this appears to be your Eclipse log. Could you provide your Android (logcat) log?

Comment: Try to change the version of the Google Play Services library you're using, and check what happens.

Comment: Yes. I have edited the post with logcat. @Mdlc

Comment: to which version should I change the Google Play Service library.. Can you provide a direct link to download the zip? because my SDK manager is not opening. When i click on sdk manager. It doesn't open. @MadEqua

Comment: Have you added the Google Play Services library dependency using the dependency manager, or did your add GooglePS any other way?

Comment: i have used dependency manager @Mdlc

Comment: You app don't add library in apk. Or GPS not installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Comment: Then how to fix it? @itvdonsk

Comment: Try update/install latest version GMS https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Comment: I don't know how check library on Eclipse. Library should be compiled with app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported Google Play services lib as a project?

It's important to import  google-play-services_lib as a project: 
`Select File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace` and click Next. 
Select Browse..., enter 
`[android-sdk-folder]/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`, and click Finish.
(See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro under "Sample Code") 
Then follow the instructions from the linked answer:

> - Import the actual source for the "google-play-services_lib" project and link it as an >Android library.
> - Do this through Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library, Add -> google-play-services_lib (you can right click on your project and
>     choose Properties, then select Android).
> - Do not add it as a dependent Project through the "Java Build Path" for your project, that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work, there's no problem. I think, you did not integrate your project with the library provided by Google. This post may helps you a lot:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eclipse#include_the_google_play_services_library

Please follow the steps thoroughly.

Comment: I had earlier followed the method for Eclipse ADT but it didn't work.. so I have switched to Android Studio and the code is working as expected. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

> Get your own google play service from your
>   adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130514\sdk\extras\google. this will work
>   defiantly.

Answer (score 1):

`ShellCommandUnresponsiveException` thrown when a shell command executed on a device takes too long to send its output.

The command may not actually be unresponsive, it just has spent too much time not outputting any thing to the console.
So this problem is not related to your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit(Answer):**

Thank you for all the answer. I appreciate it.

I Came to know about the actual problem, the Eclipse ADT was not updated and hence the error was there but after the update, it was still not working hence I switched to Android Studio and the code is now working as expected.

Thank You All